# Rails Format the date and subtracting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to subtract todays date from account expiration date in order to get remaining days, by doing this:

```
<% @accounts.each do |account| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= account.name %>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><%= account.email %>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><%= (account.expiration.try(:to_date) - Date.today).to_i %></td>
```

I'm getting this error: `undefined method '-' for nil:NilClass`

At this line: `<td><%= (account.expiration.try(:to_date) - Date.today).to_i %></td>`

Any ideas why this is not working?

Comment: because `account.expiration.try(:to_date)` is `nil`

Comment: Either `account.expiration.try(:to_date)` or `Date.today` is `nil`. You need to put a debugger in there and figure out which one it is. Its probably the former rather than the latter...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're getting is:

```
nil - Date.today
NoMethodError: undefined method `-' for nil:NilClass
```

As you're using try, then it doesn't raise any exception, but returns nil if the object being accessed doesn't respond to the method invoked. In your case it's giving you `nil`, and you can't apply `-` to a nil object.

You could move such logic to a helper, check if the attribute is being nil and return a default value, otherwise perform the operation:

```
# app/helpers/application_helper.rb
def expiration_substraction(account_expiration)
  return <default_value> if account_expiration.nil?
  (account_expiration.to_date - Date.today).to_i
end
```

This should be available for the view you're working on:

```
<%= expiration_substraction(account.expiration) %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Sebastian Palma! I'm using` try` because I have a couple of `expirations` that are `nil`. Also, what should I put inside the `<default_value>`? And how can I access this form the view, when I loop thru the accounts?

Comment: If you place this method within the app/helpers/application_helper.rb then it'd be available for any of your views. The default value is something you define for yourself to show in the view in case the account.expiration is nil and you can't perform the operation of subtracting it to Date.today.

Comment: I got this error : `application_helper.rb:4: void value expression return <1> if account_expiration.nil? ^`

Comment: at this line `return <1> if account_expiration.nil?`

Comment: Sorry, the value between `<>` is to exemplify is a custom value added by you, remove them, just `return 1 if account_expiration.nil?`.

Comment: ok now I'm getting: `undefined method 'expiration' for #<Account::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fea36585368>` I changed the helper method  to this: `(@accounts.expiration.to_date - Date.today).to_i`